# List of "Year-Month" from Current Year month to Jan-2021 in Java

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime

I have a business requirement to write a service which returns the list of Year months (01-2021,02-2021,....) starting from 01-2021 to the current year month (current : 02-2022).

Can anyone suggest me the approach that I can take to solve this in Java 8

O/P : 01-2021, 02-2021, 03-2021, 04-2021 , so on , 02-2022.

Comment: I would have a look at the `YearMonth` class in the `java.time` package: `for (YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2021, 1); !ym.isAfter(YearMonth.now()); ym=ym.plusMonths(1)) { ... }`

Comment: Well, you can use `YearMonth.plusMonths` to get the next one from any given YearMonth, `YearMonth.now` to get the current one, and `YearMonth.compareTo` to compare one `YearMonth` with another... I'd expect that to be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following would do.

```java
YearMonth now = YearMonth.now();
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2021, 1);
List<YearMonth> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (!ym.isAfter(now)) {
  list.add(ym);
  ym = ym.plusMonths(1);
}
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy");
List<String> list2 = list.stream().map(it -> it.format(format)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Should get you a list starting from 2021-1 till now.

Another option is to use a stream.

```java
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy");
long months = Period.between(LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 1), LocalDate.now()).toTotalMonths();
List<String> yms = LongStream.rangeClosed(0, months)
  .mapToObj(it -> YearMonth.now().minusMonths(it))
  .map(it -> it.format(format))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You first calculate the number of months, iterate over that number and generate the list.

Comment: That's what you get from typing things from your head :|. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you !! the above code works , but  in postman i see the below  format ["2021-01","2021-02","2021-03","2021-04","2021-05","2021-06", ,"2021-07","2021-08","2021-09","2021-10","2021-11","2021-12","2022-01","2022-02"], but what front end needs is 01-2021, 02-2021, this format

Comment: Add a `map` and convert to a list of `String` what you are seeing is the `toString` or `YearMonth`. I've edited the answer to factor this in.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.time` package has a `YearMonth` class ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html)) ideal for this use case:

```
for (YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2021, Month.JANUARY); // or ...of(2021, 1)
     !ym.isAfter(YearMonth.now());
     ym = ym.plusMonths(1))
{
    System.out.printf("%Tm-%1$TY\n", ym);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class YearMonth {
    public static void getYearMonths() {

        YearMonth nextMonth = YearMonth.now().plusMonths(1);
        YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of(2021, 01);
 
        while (nextMonth.isAfter(yearMonth)) {
        // Create a DateTimeFormatter string
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy");
        
        // Format this year-month
        System.out.println(yearMonth.format(formatter));
        yearMonth = yearMonth.plusMonths(1);
        }
    }
}
```